# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel error during TLS 1.2 connection when not in admin mode

Tags: c#, powershell, tls1.2

I've spent last two days searching for answers and still have no idea as to where to begin my investigation.

I've got both a C# .net standard library as well as a powershell script that allows me to fetch data from a REST api.  The powershell script looks like this.

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\<Thumbprint>
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri “https://some.url.to.get.my.data” -Method Get -Certificate $cert
```

Both, this script and C# code mentioned here was working for me until recently (not running as administrator).  Now it is giving me trouble and returning an error message:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:3 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri “https://some.url.to.get.my.data ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Same problem exist in my C# application.  I've set

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

I set the X509 Certificate (not shown here) and make a call using

```
HttpClient.GetStringAsync(string requestUri).Result;
```

The call hangs and never returns.

The interesting thing here is that both the Powershell and C# code works fine if I'm running the Powershell or Visual Studio in Administrator mode.

In my frustration, I tried looking at the calls between my client and the server via wireshark.  By comparing the call pattern between working and non working call, I can tell that the handshaking appears to be working correctly.  At least initially until just before the server is suppose to send the data.  The client for some reason sends a [FIN, ACK] call to the server and the connection terminates.

I welcome any suggestion you might have.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to validate the server certificate(s) manually, adding a `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` that just returns `true` (for testing). At least you'll see if it gets to that point. Assuming that the client certificate is still valid/trusted.

Comment: [Octopus Deploy](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy) and [Octopus Deploy Library](https://library.octopus.com/) probably have what you are looking for.

Comment: Is the remote host even negotiating TLS 1.2? Change the `-host` parameter here and try: `openssl s_client -host localhost -port 443 -debug -security_debug -security_debug_verbose | grep "Version=TLS"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it turns out that the problem indeed was fetching the certificate.  I initially had the certificate in the Current User account during development which worked without any issue.  Once I had moved the certificate under the Local Machine account, I started having this issue.

The solution was to give my user account permission to access the specific certificate via Certificate Manager > Right click on the Certificate > All Tasks > Manage Private Keys.  Then add my user account to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similair issue with another .NET Application, please verify if below registry keys have been set, also note that a specific patch may be reqruired based on your .NET and or OperatingSystem version for more information see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

```
$RegistryKeys = @(
    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319"
        Name = "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"
        Value = "1"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }

    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319"
        Name = "SchUseStrongCrypto"
        Value = "1"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }
    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319"
        Name = "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"
        Value = "1"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }
    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319"
        Name = "SchUseStrongCrypto"
        Value = "1"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }
    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server"
        Name = "Enabled"
        Value = "1"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }
    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server"
        Name = "DisabledByDefault"
        Value = "0"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }
    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client"
        Name = "Enabled"
        Value = "1"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }
    @{
        Path = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client"
        Name = "DisabledByDefault"
        Value = "0"
        PropertyType = "DWord"
    }
)
```

Some code to test this with:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

Foreach ($RegistryKey in $RegistryKeys) {

    # * Validate Path
    # This code will check if the Path exists.
    Write-Verbose "Processing '$($RegistryKey.Path)' '$($RegistryKey.Name)'"    
    Write-Verbose "Validating if path '$($RegistryKey.Path)' exists"
    If (-Not (Test-Path -Path $RegistryKey.Path)) {
        Write-Warning "Path '$($RegistryKey.Path)' doest not exist"
        Continue
    }
    Write-Verbose "Path '$($RegistryKey.Path)' exists"

    # * Validate Property
    # This code will check if the property exists.
    Write-Verbose "Reading properties for'$($RegistryKey.Path)'"        
    $Properties = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryKey.Path
    Write-Verbose "Validating if property '$($RegistryKey.Name)' exists"
    If (-Not ($RegistryKey.Name -in ($Properties | Get-Member).Name)) {
        Write-Warning "Property '$($RegistryKey.Name)' doest not exist"
        Continue
    }
    Write-Verbose "Property '$($RegistryKey.Name)' exists"   

    # * Validate Property value
    # This code will check if the configured value is correct.
    Write-Verbose "Validating if property value is set to '$($RegistryKey.Value)'"
    If (-Not ((Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistryKey.Path -Name $RegistryKey.Name)."$($RegistryKey.Name)" -eq $RegistryKey.Value)) {
        Write-Warning "Property value is incorrect for '$($RegistryKey.Path)' '$($RegistryKey.Name)'"
        Continue    
    }
    Write-Verbose "Property value is correct for '$($RegistryKey.Path)' '$($RegistryKey.Name)'"     
}
```